# How are torques determined in equations of motion for multibody systems?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque

In classical mechanics of multibody systems, one often ends up with equations for $n$ torques for $n$ links:

$$\tau_i= A_{ij}\ddot{\theta}_j + B_{ijk} \dot{\theta}_j \dot{\theta}_k + C_i  ,$$

with certain quantities $A$, $B$, and $C$ which can be defined elsewhere.  The aim is then usually to solve these equations numerically for $\dot{\theta}$ and $\theta$.

However, how can this be done without knowing what the torques are, because $\tau$ depends on the angles and angular speeds.

Comment: The goal it to solve for $\ddot{\theta}$ and then integrate to get $\dot{\theta}$ and $\theta$ over time.

Comment: What is the torque for a single simple pendulum, in terms of $\theta$,  $m$,  and $g$?

Comment: Given Nikodem Poplawski's "Cosmology with torsion" (actually inflationary, in spite of its subtitle, but with ECT equations of motion that have been described as hard to understand), the question seems to me to have cosmological implications, but I lack the nerve to suggest a "cosmology" tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a simulation loop which integrates $\ddot{\theta}$ to get $\dot{\theta}$ and $\theta$ at a later time.

So at each time steps follow these steps

1. Known vectors of joint speeds and angles $\dot{\boldsymbol{\theta}}_n$ and $\boldsymbol{\theta}_n$ at time $t_n$, or initial conditions for the first step. Calculate coefficient matrix $\bf A$, and vectors $\boldsymbol{B}$ and $\boldsymbol{C}$.
2. Calculate torques $$\boldsymbol{\tau}_n = \tau(t_n, \boldsymbol{\theta}_n, \dot{\boldsymbol{\theta}}_n)$$
3. Solve system for the vector of accelerations $$\ddot{\boldsymbol{\theta}}_n = \mathbf{A}^{-1}\left( \boldsymbol{\tau}_n - \boldsymbol{B}( \dot{\boldsymbol{\theta}}_n) - \boldsymbol{C} \right)$$
4. Use an integration scheme to find the joint angles and speeds at the next step $$\dot{\boldsymbol{\theta}}_{n+1} = \dot{\boldsymbol{\theta}}_n + h\, \ddot{\boldsymbol{\theta}}_n$$ $${\boldsymbol{\theta}}_{n+1} = {\boldsymbol{\theta}}_n + h\, \dot{\boldsymbol{\theta}}_n$$ $$ t_{n+1} = t_n + h$$
5. Repeat from step 1. until the target time is reached.

Of course, the integration scheme above is for illustration purposes, as typically a multistep process is used coupling together steps 1 to 4 .

To clarify, in step 2., which is the question here, you can formulate the joint torques from the free body diagrams of each body.

Joint *i* is has rotation axis direction $\boldsymbol{z}_i$ and moment vector at the joint $\boldsymbol{M}_i$ then the joint torque is

$$ \tau_i = \boldsymbol{z}_{i}\cdot\boldsymbol{M}_{i} $$

For example a simple pendulum with the pivot at the origin has moment vector due to gravity as

$$ \boldsymbol{M}_i = \pmatrix{\ell \sin \theta \\ -\ell \cos \theta \\ 0} \times \pmatrix{0 \\ - m g \\ 0} = \pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\ -m g \ell \sin \theta} $$

the joint axis is $\boldsymbol{z}_i = \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 1}^\top$ and so the joint torque is the dot product of the two

$$ \tau_i = \boldsymbol{z}_i \cdot \boldsymbol{M}_i = -m g \ell \sin \theta $$

Comment: Equation (3) B should be a vector, and A is a function of  $\theta$

Comment: @Eli - $A_{ij}$ is a matrix, $B_{ijk} \dot{\theta}_j \dot{\theta}_k$ is a vector, and $C_{i}$ is a vector. I updated the answer.

Comment: I think that step 3 should be $\ddot{\boldsymbol{\theta}}_n = \mathbf{A}^{-1}(\boldsymbol\theta_n)\left( \boldsymbol{\tau}_n - \boldsymbol{b}(\boldsymbol\theta_n~, \dot{\boldsymbol{\theta}}_n) - \boldsymbol{C} \right)$

Comment: But in step 2 how can the torques only depend on $\dot{\theta}$, would they not generally depend on $\ddot{\theta}$ as well?  I see that you can re-write as you do in Step 3, but you still have to derive $\tau$ from first principles to substitute it in.

Comment: @Tom - no at each time frame position and velocities are known, and torques are derived from those via the free body diagrams. $\tau$ can either be a motor torque (specified) or a result of an external force as in the example in the end of the answer.

Comment: Ah I see.  In your example, you mean a simple double pendulum?  So for a compound double pendulum, the joint torque for both bodies at a moment of time would be $\tau_i = - mg l \sin \theta_i$, where $l$ is the distance from the $i$-th joint to the centre of mass of the rigid body?